# An update (for,in,of) the given time slots?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> An update for the given time slots.

Is it grammatically correct? Is "update" correctly used here? Actually, I want to tell someone that there is a change in the document. So, can I say the above written statement?

Should it be like this?

> An update **for/in/of** the given time slots.

Which one is correct out of the 3 options given?

Comment: A question like your first one is easily answerable by a dictionary. In the future, when asking about the meaning of a word, please at least include a definition or two from an online dictionary, to demonstrate that you've done a little prior research, and to explain why you are still a little confused even after looking the word up.

Answer (score 2):

I'd usually say -

> An update **on** the given time slots.

[Update works as a noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/update?q=update) here and means an act of updating something or someone or an updated version of something.

As an example given there -

> An update on recently published crime figures.

Comment: I would probably use _to_ instead of _on_: _An update **to** the given time slots_, but this is one of those cases where more than one preposition could be used.

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative will be to use updated (as you have mentioned that document has already been changed).

So you can say:

> The document has the **updated** time slots

If you want to stick to your original sentence, there is no harm in that as it is grammatically correct too:

> the document has an update **for** the given time slots.

It would also be correct to use:

> there is an update **in/to** the document **for/on** the time slots.

Althogh, I would use "for" for the 2nd option.

Comment: yes, but when you *notify* someone, generally we say, "*hey, there's an update on....*

Comment: @MaulikV: I agree. As J.R. said, this is one of those cases where more than one propositions could be used. And there is nothing grammatically wrong in the original version.

Comment: There is an update *for* you. You are promoted! Neither *of* nor *on* fits here!

Comment: @MaulikV - That is a different context entirely; the update is _for_ the other person, not _to_ or _on_ some document. Also, I have no problem with _an update **for** the given time slots_.

Comment: @J.R. Okay, I was concerned about *update for/on/in*.

Comment: Based on the info given by @J.R. in his last comment, i have given **an update to my comment for the example**. See what I did there?? :D

Comment: @Maulik - There is no set preposition that goes with _update_: I have an update **for** Brian. We're waiting for an update **on** the school closings. An update **to** the software will be released next week. Please visit our website for the latest updates **in** the material. The document has an update **for** the given time slots. Here is [an update  **about** the next update](http://steamcommunity.com/games/242880/announcements/detail/1963867850699972306). It depends on what is being updated, and how it's being updated.

Comment: @J.R. Got it. I answered what looked natural to me.